# Websocket e CakePHP

Tags: javascript, cakephp, websocket, chat

Como integrar Websocket em um sistema em CakePHP 1.2 que roda num servidor Apache com um banco de dados PostgreSQL?

Preciso fazer um chat, e todas as conversas serão salvas nesse banco, separados por usuários do sistema, como o Facebook.

O sistema de chat atual usa polling em Ajax, mas o servidor está ficando sobrecarregado as vezes.

Um sistema socket resolveria a solução.